# how to populate a table on sqlite3 using user input?

Tags: python-2.7, sqlite, user-input

I'm trying to create a simple program. It should receive user input-data (a list of 4 numbers) and store it on a data base, along with some other information (date and time of input and so on). So, my questions are the following:

- Is there a way to populate a database (using python and sqlite3) with user-input data?
- How can I, automatically, assign a value to each new entry (for example, an ID or date&time?

I'm trying to learn by doing, not getting the work done. Also, I'm pretty new to programming so I would like just to be pointed in the right direction.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. It's definitely possible to populate a SQLite DB with python. Google "python sqlite3" finds this page: https://docs.python.org/2/library/sqlite3.html.
2. Read the first entry in the [SQLite FAQ](http://www.sqlite.org/faq.html) titled "How do I create an AUTOINCREMENT field".